# How to center hero image on mobile phone

Tags: html, css

I'm building a simple "Coming soon" page and trying to figure out how to position my hero image in the center. Currently it looks fine on desktop but on mobile the text nicely centered but the hero image is not. You can check it out for yourself here: https://quintillion.ai/

I would like to have it such that the image is always positioned in the center and if need be it would just show a black background above and below the image.

Here is my html and css code:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/1000/1000");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: black;
  background-position: center;
  background-position-y: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height:100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.overlay {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0 1000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;  
  justify-content: center; /* Added */
  align-items: center; /* Added */
}

.text {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
  color: #ffffff;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 60px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 48px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

p {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="text">
    <h1>Quintillion AI</h1>
    <h2>Coming soon</h2>
    <p>
      We are currently in stealth mode, building AI Assistants for the future of work.
      <br>Please check back soon for updates.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you use `background-size: cover;` there won't even be black parts. And yeah, remove the bg-y posution.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Awesome - that worked. If you post it as an asnwer I can award you the points.

Comment: @Reddspark just add `background-position: left/right/center/bottom;` in `body` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a background-image cover the entire space use `background-size: cover;`. Here's a shorthand for your code:

```css
body {
  background: #000 url("https://picsum.photos/1000/1000") no-repeat center / cover;
  /* remove the other background-* properties ... */
  /* other styles ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

You didn't add `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column` to `.text` class.

```css
.text {
  display: flex; /* here */
  flex-direction: column; /* here */
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

and add CSS in `<p>` tag

```css
p {
  text-align: center; /* here */
}
```

#### Example

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/1000/1000");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: black;
  background-position: center;
  background-position-y: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height:100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.overlay {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0 1000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;  
  justify-content: center; /* Added */
  align-items: center; /* Added */
}

.text {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
  color: #ffffff;
  display: flex; /* here */
  flex-direction: column; /* here */
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 60px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 48px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

p {
  text-align: center; /* here */
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="text">
    <h1>Quintillion AI</h1>
    <h2>Coming soon</h2>
    <p>
      We are currently in stealth mode, building AI Assistants for the future of work.
      <br>Please check back soon for updates.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That solution only modified the text though not the image? I needed the background image to move down when viewed on mobile, not the text. Have managed to fix based on Roko's answer though.